# Calculating distance in a form AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, google-maps

I am having a struggle with AngularJS.
I am building a simple for to do a price calculation based on chosen time and distance from a set location. My problem is that I just don't know how to do a distance calculation in AngularJS. Can one of you guys help?

[image: The form I]

With Kind Regards,
Pim Praat

Comment: can you add more details ?

Comment: Calculating distance has nothing to do with angularjs. You need the coordinates of the 2 points and then calculate distance between them in js using mathematics (google the exact formula for your use case).

Comment: Thanks, but can I do that inside my AngularJS? And I made a JSFiddle:: http://jsfiddle.net/pimpraat/aabn1Lwc/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the google maps API to get the time & distance between 2 points. Then you calculate your price:

http://google.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC